# Polygons from Line layer grouped by value

Tags: qgis

Is there a method to create polygons from a line layer, grouped by data values?

I have a line shapefile layer with +/-1000 records, about half of the records have a unique group value that designates them by a geographic area.  I'm currently symbolizing the lines based on the group that they belong to, but I'd also like to be able to create a layer with a polygon for each group.

Comment: Do those lines *form* Polygons/closed rings? Or do you need e.g. a convex hull?

Comment: It sounds like [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/310906/81764) will work for you. Just be sure to choose the unique group value field from the dropdown menu called "field (optional set if features should be grouped by class)". I'm not sure how it will handle if some features have a unique group value and others don't; you may need to use the Field Calculator to fill in a value for the ones that don't have it.

Comment: Much appreciated csk!   The toolbox -> Vector Geometry -> Minimum Bounding Geometry tool from the link you provided was the solution I was looking for.