# Extracting road parts from a vector

Tags: qgis, vector

I have vector drawings as in the image. The sections in these vectors represent physical roads. Is there an easy way to extract these road sections to a different vector layer? Or will this be a manual work?

[image]

Comment: Use OpenStreetMap data for the relevant extent, e.g. with QuickOSM plugin so you don't have to recreate streets that already exist in vector format.

Comment: The data in this vector is official data. So the places shown as roads in this vector may not physically exist. I think OpenStreetMap only gives road data that physically exists.

Comment: OK, than give a bit more context. We only see a satellite image and some polygons. Not clear what that has to do with your question. See [tour]

Comment: It seems to me that the data you're trying to obtain is missing, you've only got what looks to be land parcels, the roads are omitted. You could enclose the data you have with a convex hull https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283111/creating-minimum-convex-polygon-around-points-in-qgis and erase https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62949/seeking-qgis-equivalent-of-arcgis-erase-tool that with the data  you have, that would leave the roads as the un-erased polygons. Then a little bit of manual editing to clean off the areas created by the convex hull that are outside your data area.